# Amazon Lex Initializatoin and time zone issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, timezone, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

Can I declare request attribute "x-amz-lex:time-zone" in lambda initialization to change the time zone of amazon lex chat bot. If can, how should i write?

Comment: Seems to be covered [in these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html#special-time-zone).  Did you try?

Comment: I tried. That Documents are very high level. I just want to know where can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because the "initialization and validation" Lambda Function comes **after** Lex processes the input, with the time-zone setting already used to format date and time values.

The other thing to note is that `requestAttributes` are only used by Lex in the incoming request, not in the response. Here is what is meant when we differentiate between request and response:

[image]

---

This is the relevant line in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html#special-time-zone) (emphasis added):

> "A user-defined request attribute is data that you send to your bot in each **request**. You send the information in the amz-lex-request-attributes header of a **PostContent request** or in the requestAttributes field of a **PostText request**."

---

So here is where `requestAttributes` need to be added:
[image]

And `requestAttributes` can only be added by [PostContent API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) or [PostText API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html).

Comment: I got it. Thanks Jay!